# Thread wont run as a controlled seperated thread

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading

I've got a measurement hardware device that i'd like to control trough a class. I want to be able to Start and Stop it and have it measuring in its own thread. So that width 2 buttons I can start and stop sampling measurements, therefore I created MeasurementsStart() and MeasurementsStop() both are called from 2 buttons.

When inside the function TakeMeasurements() I end
width WorkThread.Abort();
VS2017, says not all code path returns a value.

When i end it width " Throw new NotImplementedException " in place, the code does compile it runs but when i press MeasurementsStart button then the workthread keeps runing, though the rest of program freezes.

Its not clear to me how I should end this function to get this start / stop behaviour.

The code of taking an actual measurements has been replaced here with a random number.

```
   Public static Class Measure
   {
        public static List<double> Samples;
        private static Thread workThread;
        private static volatile bool stopThread = false;


        public static void MeasurementsStop()
        {
            if (workThread != null)
            {
                stopThread = true;
                workThread.Join(); // pauses till Thread exits.
                workThread = null;
            }
        }

        public static void MeasurementsStart()
        {
            Samples = new List<double>();
            if (workThread == null)
            {
                stopThread = false;
                workThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TakeMeasurements()));
                workThread.IsBackground = true;
                workThread.Start();
            }
        }

        private static ThreadStart TakeMeasurements()
        {
            while (!stopThread )
            {System.Console.Beep(200, 200);
               Samples.Add(new Random().Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue));
              System.Console.Beep(400, 200);
            }
           workThread.Abort();
           //   throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Comment: *Don't* use `Abort` to cancel a thread. `Abort` is the big red switch under the security covering opened by two officers with keys in chains. Use CancellationToken to check whether an operation needs to terminate. BTW the `static volatile bool stopThread` isn't thread safe. Before CancellationToken people used ManualResetEvent and other similar constructs, never global variables

Comment: Use a timer if you want to take periodic measurements in a background thread, not an infinite `while` loop.  Use *Tasks* instead of raw threads in general to be able to combine asynchronous operations, and be able to handle their results safely - `Samples` isn't thread safe. A ConcurrentQueue would probably be better

Comment: that 'token' ? is the bool stopThread, i can remove "workThread.Abort()  but it still wont work, i thought it should be in there, but it was already a non working fix.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in this case the measuring device has to be read out fast, when ready, but for each sample it goes trough a random initialization time. thats why i didnt use a timer, but a looping retrieval.

Comment: The CancellationToken works. It *doesn't* abort the thread, which is a very serious bug. The code checks whether cancellation is requested and exits the loop gracefully. There are a *lot* of duplicate questions already

Comment: Check [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with cancelling the thread, it's that you're running the `TakeMeasurements()` function on the main thread.

In your line `workThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TakeMeasurements()));` you are *calling* your `TakeMeasurements` function (because it has parentheses on the end) instead of passing a reference to the function as the place to start the new thread.

Change the `TakeMeasurements` function signature to return void (as it has no return), and change

```
workThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TakeMeasurements()));
```

to

```
workThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TakeMeasurements));
```

(note without the parenthesis).

As for cancelling the `TakeMeasurements` thread (and assuming you're using a blocking method of reading such as TCP), you have two approaches.
You can either:

- Put a timeout on the blocking call so the thread wakes up periodically to check `stopThread`, or
- Use a `CancellationToken`, as long as your blocking call supports accepting a `CancellationToken` as a parameter.

Both will work, but will be structured differently.  If the blocking method you use supports a `CancellationToken`, that would be my preference.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes now it works, and it makes sense. I was allready thinking about constructs with cancelation and rewrote most of it, and got it bit stuck on that too, thanks !